# go to source with custom messages during compile?

Tags: macros, c++builder, c++builder-xe

In Visual Studio I can include the following macros in the source and during build the message is printed out.  I can then double click on the message in the build message window and go to the line of source.

```
#define _QUOTE(x) # x
#define QUOTE(x) _QUOTE(x)
#define __FILE__LINE__ __FILE__ "(" QUOTE(__LINE__) ") : "
#pragma message ( __FILE__LINE__ "Notify user of something in code" )
```

Is it possible to do the same in Builder C++?

I think not, as there seems to be more information in the build messages window in Builder C++ that allows the 'view source' option or double click command to work.

C++ Builder XE.

I have included the Delphi tag with this question as lots of Delphi users also use Builder C++.

Comment: If you're happy with my answer, could you accept it please?  (Otherwise feedback on why it's wrong / improvable would be good.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent in C++ Builder is the `#warning` directive. The line:

```
#warning Test warning message here
```

Shows the following in the Messages pane:

[image: A warning message in the Messages pane]

This acts like any other compiler message, and double-clicking it takes you to the line of code.

The `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros do not expand inside a message you define using `#warning` - it takes text and spits it out exactly as written.  However, you don't need to use them since the message that's emitted includes the file and line number anyway.

If you want to write out an error message (as Delphi allows you to - `$MESSAGE` has a level, from memory, of hint, warning or error) you can use `#error`.  It works the same as `#warning` and stops compilation at that line just like any other error compiling, so

```
#error This is an error message
```

gives

[image: An error message in the Messages pane]

I'm using [C++ Builder 2010](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder), but I'm moderately sure that these directives have worked for many versions.

(By the way, tagging a C++ Builder question 'delphi' is normally fine, since many questions about the IDE or VCL will be equally answerable by both communities. I do it all the time.  This is probably not one of those questions, since Delphi people are unlikely to know about specific C++ Builder compiler directives.  Tagging 'c++-builder' by itself is fine.)

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi you can include a message directive. For example:

```
{$MESSAGE WARN 'To be or not to be'}
```

Which would output a warning in the build messages. That build message is just as clickable as any other compiler error/warning/hint and clicking it will take you to the location of the {$MESSAGE ...} directive in the source.

I do not know as I do not use C++ builder, but I would assume that C++ Builder supports a similar technique...

Comment: #pragma warn turns warnings on or off for C++ Builder.

#pragma message displays messages, but they are not clickable

Comment: This is an important point, because C++-Builder projects may also contain Delphi Units. I think you should add a word about it. I'd replace the last sentence to make the question on-topic.